Is "bullshit" still considered offensive when used in a narrower sense?
The OALD defines "bullshit" as "an offensive word for ideas, statements or beliefs that you think are silly or not true", giving nonsense as a synonym and no further details.
However, it was pointed out in this thread, that it includes connotations of being deceitful, deliberately misleading, bluffing etc.
This connotation is apparently prevalent in book titles such as "On Bullshit", "Bullshit Jobs" or "Calling Bullshit".
So, while it seems obvious to me that declaring a statement in a discussion as "bullshit" would be very much offensive, I was wondering whether it has become something like a technical term in the contexts of fake news / criticism of the job world / cheating with statistics so that its use might be acceptable here.

I think you need to distinguish two things - being offensive merely because of the word 'shit', and, a further, cumulative annoyance caused because bullshit material is insincere and/or dishonest. When I worked in a UK legal organisation dealing with senior legal officials, I and (they) were OK if I talked about 'BS', but saying the word in full would have been too much. Avoid it in anything more formal than beery conversations with colleagues after work when you are sure senior people are not listening.

Thank you! Yes, I can absolutely follow you in that this distinction should be taken into consideration. So when you used "Bee Ess" in a formal live (oral) conversation, you used the term because it carried these connotations (so "nonsense" would not have been precise enough), and the reason you shortened it was because of the taboo status of "shit", is that right? It still surprises me, though, that it does not seem to be a problem to publish serious (even though light-hearted, popular) books with an offensive word in their titles!

My boss would not have liked me to say 'we both know that a recent government statement that you mentioned is bullshit', but rather obliquely saying that it may be considered er, BS by some people was a better (more prudent) thing to say.

Likewise, saying 'I couldn't possibly comment on that' meant 'YES, but I can't say so'.

@wgtwob Using "Bullshit" in the title is meant to convey a strident straightforwardness. By using a term that is slightly unacceptable in business settings, the author is trying to sell themselves as a "straight shooter" who ignores niceties and tells the unvarnished truth.

It depends on the work. Cops use it and so do many others. One thing are comments to peers, another is a formal situation, like a board meeting. Also, the verb and noun can have different meanings. To bullshit someone is to say untrue things.

@Lambie Would you say that "to bullshit" as a verb is linguistically less offensive than "bullshit" as a noun (notwithstanding the fact that it conveys harsh criticism)?

Everything depends on who and where it is said.

Questions along the lines of "is [such and such a word] offensive" are likely to attract opinion-based answers. What one person considers offensive, another might not. This is why content warnings exist, such as age ratings on movies, so that individuals can make a choice to see or hear content that others do not wish to.
Actually, the way in which movies are classified based on language is a very good barometer of what is generally considered to be offensive by the majority, or at least a significant number of people so as to be an indicator it isn't language for 'general' use.
The British Board for Film Classification (BBFC) have the following categories for bad language:

'very mild'
'mild'
'moderate'
'strong'
'very strong'

According to this resource, "shit" is considered to be 'mild' by the BBFC, which would restrict it from being used in a 'U'-rated filim (universal, or suitable for all). However it would be allowed in film rated 'PG' or '12/12A' (the US equivalent of PG-13), which suggests that most people would not want children younger than 12 to hear the word, although some parents may accept their children younger than that have already been exposed to it (hence the 'parental guidance' rating).
The BBFC also make a distinction between a word being used for emphasis and the same word being used "in a violent way". The latter is considered to be far worse, so context is important, too.
Most people would not use language that could be considered offensive by some in the workplace or in the company of people not well known to you, as you may not know how they personally feel about such words. For me, that rule of thumb would make 'bull shit' an expression to avoid in the workplace.

Thank you for this interesting intercultural lesson, I was completely unaware how much attention film classification in English-speaking countries pays to language! What I take home from this, and all the comments, is that I myself need to be more sensitive about this word in particular.

Oh come on. I would use bullshit with peers, even if they aren't my friends.

@Lambie I'm 100% sure it comes out of your mouth daily.

Probably, but only with peers.
